# Rest api authentication: how to get the token the first time

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

Thanks to this page [api_key_authentication](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html) I have an authentication system which works well.
So, basically every user has his own `api_key` field (stored into the fos_user table), when I perform a request with any `api_key` from fos_user I see in the response that the user is recognized.

The question is: What does an API user do to retrieve his `api_key`?

Comment: They generally receive and store their key before they start using the API

Comment: Yes I agree with you and I'd like to know how I can do it? should I create a new controller authenticate for example that return the user token if his credentials (username/email and password are good) or ...?

Comment: That is definitely way to do it.   A lot of places will also provide it once when the consumer signs up for API access.  Try signing up for an API key at one of your favorite websites and see how they do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate api key and send it to the user (somehow) or make auth api where user send you his login and password and then you generate and send him his api key (this is the most known way).

Comment: That's the first thought I got when I start working on the API, then I thought either symfony or fosrestbundle has got certainly something done for this purpose. Ok then thx